# Apache server allow access from the local network

Tags: fedora, apache-httpd

I have installed fedora server, and I cannot seem to get web requests through to it.
I can ping it fine, and apache is functioning fine on the machine as far as I know.

I have the listen on httpd.conf as

```
Listen *:80
```

and the Server Name as

```
ServerName 192.168.1.133:80
```

cause it was complaining about it in console but with or without the line it doesn't seem to work

```
[root@localhost conf]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)

[root@localhost conf]# netstat -ntulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1384/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1384/smbd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      826/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1044/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      1384/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      1384/smbd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1044/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      826/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           945/dhclient
udp        0      0 192.168.1.255:137       0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.113:137       0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:137             0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.255:138       0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 192.168.1.113:138       0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:138             0.0.0.0:*                           1441/nmbd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52142           0.0.0.0:*                           945/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::41117                :::*                                945/dhclient
```

Comment: Can you post the output of the following commands; ```cat /etc/redhat-release```, ```netstat -ntulp```.

Comment: Its in the OP, ipv6 is open on port 80 but I read that it should work on an ipv4 because of backwards compatibility but it was the only response on the thread...

I also installed samba while I was waiting around (hence all the random ports) and it cant be seen on my windows PC either

Comment: Ok, is the firewall running on the machine? ```firewall-cmd --state```. If so you'll need to add some rules. I can help with that.

Comment: yep it is, I will need a hand with that :L

Comment: Ok, firewalld is a little more complex than previously used iptables, the best rule to start with would probably be; ```firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80```. That is assuming you want anybody to be able to listen connect on port 80.

Comment: anyone on the local network right? when I ran it it wanted a protocol so I put tcp, was that correct? also do I now need to run a reload command?

Comment: Yes, tcp is correct, yes reload the firewall with  ```firewall-cmd --reload```. Further to that I've just spotted you could of also ran the following command instead of the one above; ```firewall-cmd --add-service=http```.

Comment: it was probably just port 80 that worked but I added the http service too and its working, thanks!

Comment: No problem, I'll add an answer in so other people can see the issue was resolved too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache requests were being blocked on the firewall. The following commands were run to allow all requests through the firewall.

`firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload`

It should also be possible to use the following command instead of allowing port 80;

`firewall-cmd --add-service=http
firewall-cmd --reload`